# zookeeper write failure handling

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a question on how zookeeper handles write failures. Let us assume, there are 3 nodes, and write succeeds on 1 but fails on 2, I know zookeeper will return error. But what happens to successful write on one node? Is that rolled back or changes are persisted with an expectation of being replicated to other nodes *eventually*?

Comment: master is response for write,send the write to the slaves,if half of the slaves response write no error,then the master send commit action to the slaves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zookeeper uses atomic messaging system. It's very nicely explained in the following [article](https://distributedalgorithm.wordpress.com/tag/zookeeper/):

> ZooKeeper uses a variation of two-phase-commit protocol for replicating transactions to followers. When a leader receive a change update from a client it generate a transaction with sequel number c and the leader’s epoch e and send the transaction to all followers. A follower adds the transaction to its history queue and send ACK to the leader. When a leader receives ACK’s from a quorum it send the the quorum COMMIT for that transaction. A follower that accept COMMIT will commit this transaction unless c is higher than any sequence number in its history queue. It will wait for receiving COMMIT’s for all its earlier transactions (outstanding transactions) before commiting.

Also [official documentation](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.6/zookeeperInternals.html#sc_atomicBroadcast) can be very useful.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links. Great article!